# How to see if transitive dependency versions have been overwritten

Tags: maven

My pom references a parent pom with a lot of declared dependencies in the `dependenyManagement` section. This overwrites the version of a transitive dependency and causes runtime problems.

To solve this I now declare the transitive dependency as an explicit dependency, but it took me a while to figure out the problem. I would have noticed much sooner, if `mvn dependency:tree` would have shown me that the version was overwritten, but it did not.

Can you tell me how I can quickly see, where the versions of my dependency originate from and how I can see whether a transitive dependency was affected by the parent pom or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true
```

ought to do the trick. Alternativ, you can use:

```
mvn dependency:tree -X
```

Using Maven 3.3.9 and 3.5.2 (Both default to version 2.10 of `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ xxx ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] xxx:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[INFO] |  \- (javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.junit:jar:4.7.0.201704051617-r:test
[INFO] |  \- (org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r:test - version managed from 4.7.0.201704051617-r; omitted for conflict with 4.7.0.201704051617-r)
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.junit.http:jar:4.7.0.201704051617-r:test
[INFO] |  +- (org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r:test - version managed from 4.7.0.201704051617-r; omitted for conflict with 4.7.0.201704051617-r)
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.http.server:jar:4.7.0.201704051617-r:test
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r:test - version managed from 4.7.0.201704051617-r; omitted for conflict with 4.7.0.201704051617-r)
[INFO] |  +- (org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.junit:jar:4.7.0.201704051617-r:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:test (version managed from 9.3.17.v20170317)
[INFO] |     \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:test - omitted for conflict with 9.3.19.v20170502)
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.3.19.v20170502:test
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:test (version managed from 9.3.19.v20170502)
[INFO] |     +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:test
[INFO] |     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:test
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:test
[INFO] |        \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
```

If you are using Eclipse with the M2 plugin, the tab "Dependency Hierarchy" on the POM will display omitted versions as well.

Comment: Verbose parameter does not seem to yield extra information on maven 3.3.9

Comment: That's strange, I just tried it on 3.3.9 and 3.5.2.

Comment: Verbose works for me on 3.5.2 - on 3.3.9 it even tells me that verbose is not supported. mvn dependency:tree -X seems to work on both

Answer (score 0):

Use these plugins

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html

Run command

```
mvn dependency:list
```

and

```
help:effective-pom
```

then compare two lists.

Comment: dependency:list does not seem to yield extra information regarding overwirtten transitive dependencies on maven 3.3.9. Effective-pom is too verbose to use for quick insight over what is happening.